# Hide table row by default - push button to reveal?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which one row is used for user input. I want to have this row hidden by default and be shown on the push of a button. Sadly I can't get it working.

Here is my attempt:

HTML Table

```
<tbody class="txlist" id="data_table">
           <tr id="addtx">
             <td><input type="date" id="new_date" placeholder="Date"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_account" placeholder="Account"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_category" placeholder="Category"></td>
             <td><input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
             <td><input type="button" id="save_button3" value="✔" class="save1" onclick="add_row();">
             <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="nonew()"></td>
           </tr>
...
```

HTML Button

```
<button class="float" id="addnewtx" onclick="addnewtx">
         <a>+</a>
       </button>
```

CSS

```
#addtx{
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function addnewtx(){
  document.getElementById("addtx").style.display="inline-block";
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` seem not to be the right display-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in your onclick method call of the button you should also use the
parenthesis, I mean:

```
onclick="addnewtx();"
```

The semicolon is not obligatory, but is always a good practice.

Comment: This worked, thanks mate! It's so frustrating missing the little things...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `table-row`

```
function addnewtx(){
  document.getElementById("addtx").style.display="table-row";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ended up using "table"

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content= 
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  
    <title>table</title> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #addtx{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
</head> 
  
<body> 
<button class="float" id="addnewtx" onclick="addnewtx()">
 <a>+</a>
</button>
<table>
  <tbody class="tbl-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
</body> 
  <script>
    var count = 0;
    function addnewtx(){

      var html = `<tr id="addtx${count}" class="tbl-row" style="display: inline-block;">
      <td><input type="date" id="new_date" placeholder="Date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_account" placeholder="Account"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_category" placeholder="Category"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="save_button3" value="✔" class="save1" onclick="add_row();">
      <input type="button" value="" class="delete" onclick="nonew(${count})"></td>
    </tr>`;
      var node = document.getElementsByClassName("tbl-body")[0].innerHTML;
      document.getElementsByClassName("tbl-body")[0].innerHTML  = node + html;
      // document.getElementById("addtx").style.display="inline-block";
      count++;
    }

    function nonew(count)
    {
      document.getElementById("addtx"+count).remove();
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

[something more](https://one7techlab.com)